# How to check if an NVIDIA GPU is available on my system?

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia

Is there a simple way to check if an NVIDIA GPU is available on my system **using only standard libraries**? I've already seen other answers where they recommend using PyTorch or TensorFlow but that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to know how to do this on both Windows and Linux. Thanks!

Comment: You have a windows or linux system?

Comment: I have both and I'd like to know how to do that on both of them. I'll update my question, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I don't think you are going to find a direct standard library solution, but if you used `platform` and `ctypes` you could roll your own. Seems like a lot of work that others have already potentially done and maintain such as `wmi` on windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you have Nvidia drivers installed, the command `nvidia-smi` outputs a neat table giving you information about your GPU, CUDA, and driver setup.

By checking whether or not this command is present, one can know whether or not an Nvidia GPU is present.

Do note that this code will only work if both an Nvidia GPU *and* appropriate drivers are installed.

This code should work on both Linux and Windows, and the only library it uses is subprocess, which is a standard library.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_output('nvidia-smi')
    print('Nvidia GPU detected!')
except Exception: # this command not being found can raise quite a few different errors depending on the configuration
    print('No Nvidia GPU in system!')
```

Comment: Prefer `except Exception` over bare `except`! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except

Comment: I completely forgot that was a thing! I'm so used to finding every possible exception from a block of code on every platform... Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Following code shows if cuda available. cuda is in contact with gpu

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
```

Comment: `pip install torch==1.12+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html`

Comment: But I don't know the difference between `torch.cuda.is_available()` and `torch.backends.cudnn.enabled`, could someone give the explanation?

Comment: the question specifically asked WITHOUT using pytorch so this answers is not relevant here. Please consider modifying/removing it